# Print two colums in css with Zurb Foundation 4

Tags: css, printing, sass, zurb-foundation

My code looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" media="all">
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="large-6 column">
        Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 column">
        Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in the browser it looks like it is supposed to be
[image: Browser]

But when I want to print it - it acts like mobile/tablet view
[image]

I need to have exactly two visible colums on a DIN A4 page as well as in the browser. Is there a way to handle it. Or even a better framework than Zurb.Foundation 4 for this problem?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile you should add classes `small-12` to the container (i.e. where you have `large-12`) and `small-6` to where you have `large-6`. For the print I suggest adding e.g. a custom `print-6` class that has 50% width and floats accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever have this problem. Try Bootstrap since there is no real solution in Foundation yet. At least I didn't find one.

Bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    Lorem ipsum 
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    Lorem ipsum 
 </div>
</div>
```